# xlwings not reading config file information

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm attempting to automate an install for my team that requires the use of xlwings.

My understanding is that is that if you go to the ribbon within Excel and leave the Interpreter and PYTHONPATH fields blank, xlwings will then look for a config file that's saved in the home directory in a folder called .xlwings. (c:users/USERNAME/.xlwings/xlwings.config).

I've set up the folder and file in the above location. The config file only has two lines:

```
"INTERPRETER_WIN","C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe"
"PYTHONPATH","C:\Users\USERNAME\OneDrive - Global (1)\Database\pythonProject"
```

When I run code, I get an error message that the script cannot be found. If I copy and paste the paths out of the file and into Excel, it works fine.

Am I misunderstanding how the configuration works?

Comment: No, the ribbon saves its details in the 'xlwings.conf' file located in the user directory. You can override this 'common' file for an individual workbook by placing a 'xlwings.conf' file in the  workbook’s directory. The alternate to the file/ribbon config is the 'xlwings.conf' sheet that is created but renamed '_xlwings.conf' with xlwings quickstart. If that sheet is renamed to 'xlwings.conf' then it takes precedence over the external 'xlwings.conf' file wherever it's located. See [Config Hierarchy](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#config-hierarchy) and explanations below it.